# How to solve Lorenz 96 model using Runge–Kutta method?

Tags: python, differential-equations, runge-kutta, lorenz-system

I have written the below code to solve Lorenz 96 model using Runge–Kutta method, but the results are not reliable as can be seen in the below figure:

[image]

The correct relationship between three variables is as follows:

[image]

How can I modify the code to solve the problem correctly? For more information regarding Lorenz 96, see [Lorenz 96 model- Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorenz_96_model)

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
   
###############################################################################

# Define Lorenz 96 function

# These are our constants
N = 3  # Number of variables
F = 8  # Forcing


def L96(v, t):
    """Lorenz 96 model with constant forcing"""
    # Setting up vector
    dv_dt = np.zeros(N)
    # Loops over indices (with operations and Python underflow indexing handling edge cases)
    for i in range(N):
        dv_dt[i] = (v[(i + 1) % N] - v[i - 2]) * v[i - 1] - v[i] + F
    return dv_dt
   

#define the given range t
t0=0
tn=100
h=0.005

#define number of steps (n)

time_range=np.arange(t0, tn, h)

# preallocate space
v0=np.zeros((len(time_range)+1, 1, N))
t=np.zeros(len(time_range)+1)

v0[0][0][0] += 0.01  # Add small perturbation to the first variable
L96(v0[0][0],0)

# Solve Runge-Kutta
for i in range (len(time_range)):
    print(i)
    dv_dt=L96(v0[i][0],t[i])
    
    k1=dv_dt[0]
    l1=dv_dt[1]
    m1=dv_dt[2]
    
    k2=L96([v0[i][0][0]+0.5*k1*h,v0[i][0][1]+0.5*l1*h,v0[i][0][2]+0.5*m1*h],t[i]+h/2)
    l2=L96([v0[i][0][0]+0.5*k1*h,v0[i][0][1]+0.5*l1*h,v0[i][0][2]+0.5*m1*h],t[i]+h/2)
    m2=L96([v0[i][0][0]+0.5*k1*h,v0[i][0][1]+0.5*l1*h,v0[i][0][2]+0.5*m1*h],t[i]+h/2)
  
    k3=L96([v0[i][0][0]+0.5*k2[0]*h,v0[i][0][1]+0.5*l2[0]*h,v0[i][0][2]+0.5*m2[0]*h],t[i]+h/2)
    l3=L96([v0[i][0][0]+0.5*k2[1]*h,v0[i][0][1]+0.5*l2[1]*h,v0[i][0][2]+0.5*m2[1]*h],t[i]+h/2)
    m3=L96([v0[i][0][0]+0.5*k2[2]*h,v0[i][0][1]+0.5*l2[2]*h,v0[i][0][2]+0.5*m2[2]*h],t[i]+h/2)
  
    k4=L96([v0[i][0][0]+0.5*k3[0]*h,v0[i][0][1]+0.5*l3[0]*h,v0[i][0][2]+0.5*m3[0]*h],t[i]+h/2)
    l4=L96([v0[i][0][0]+0.5*k3[1]*h,v0[i][0][1]+0.5*l3[1]*h,v0[i][0][2]+0.5*m3[1]*h],t[i]+h/2)
    m4=L96([v0[i][0][0]+0.5*k3[2]*h,v0[i][0][1]+0.5*l3[2]*h,v0[i][0][2]+0.5*m3[2]*h],t[i]+h/2)
  
    v0[i+1][0][0] = v0[i][0][0] + h*(k1 +2*k2[0]  +2*k3[0]   +k4[0])/6      # final equations
    v0[i+1][0][1] = v0[i][0][1] + h*(l1  +2*k2[1]   +2*k3[1]    +k4[1])/6
    v0[i+1][0][2] = v0[i][0][2] + h*(m1+2*k2[2] +2*k3[2]  +k4[2])/6
    t[i+1]=time_range[i]

###############################################################################

v_array=np.array(v0)
v_array.shape

v1=v_array[:,0][:,0]
v2=v_array[:,0][:,1]
v3=v_array[:,0][:,2]


fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(1, 2,constrained_layout=True,figsize=(10, 4))  
ax1.plot(v1,v3) 
ax1.set_title('v1 vs v2')    
ax2.plot(v2,v3)
ax2.set_title('v2 vs v3')    
    
# Plot 3d plot of v1,v2, and v3
from mpl_toolkits import mplot3d

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8, 5))
ax = plt.axes(projection='3d', elev=40, azim=-50)
ax.plot3D(v1, v2, v3)
ax.set_xlabel('$v1$')
ax.set_ylabel('$v2$')
ax.set_zlabel('$v3$')
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not really sure what your motivation is to tear the vectorization apart again into lines for individual components. In any case, this is wrong. Your time loop should be as simple as

```python
for i in range(len(time)-1):
    v[i+1] = RK4_step(lambda t,y:L96(y,t),time[i],v[i],time[i+1]-time[i])
```

where the method stepper is just the cook-book code

```python
def RK4_step(f,t,y,h):
    k1 = h*f(t,y)
    k2 = h*f(t+0.5*h, y+0.5*k1)
    k3 = h*f(t+0.5*h, y+0.5*k2)
    k4 = h*f(t+h, y+k3)
    return y+(k1+2*k2+2*k3+k4)/6
```

Thus there is no hard-coded limitation to 3 components, the code components are universal, the `L96` function can be used with any number of numerical solvers from libraries or self-implemented, the stepper and time loop for RK4 is valid for any other system of differential equations.

Note that in the wikipedia example there are `N=5` components where the 3D plot is constructed from the first 3 of them. For `N=3` you get indeed convergence to a fixed point that looks like a straight line, for `N=4` it appears as if there is a limit cycle, only for `N=5` does the solution start to look chaotic.

[image: 3D plot for N=4 components]
[image: 3D plot for N=5 components]

Having a 3-dimensional array makes sense if computing several trajectories at once. (But only with a fixed-step methods or if guaranteed that they stay close together, else the step-size control will be inappropriate for most of the trajectories most of the time.) The full script for that adaptation reads

```
# Define Lorenz 96 function

# These are our constants
N = 4  # Number of variables
F = 8  # Forcing


def L96(t, v):
    """Lorenz 96 model with constant forcing"""
    # Setting up vector
    dv_dt = 0*v
    # Loops over indices (with operations and Python underflow indexing handling edge cases)
    for i in range(N):
        dv_dt[i] = (v[(i + 1) % N] - v[i - 2]) * v[i - 1] - v[i] + F
    return dv_dt
   

#define the given range t
t0=0
tn=100
h=0.005

#define number of steps (n)

time = np.arange(t0, tn, h)
v = np.zeros([len(time),N,3], float)
v[0] +=F
v[0,0,0] -= 0.005
v[0,0,1] += 0.005
v[0,0,2] += 0.01
for i in range(len(time)-1):
    v[i+1] = RK4_step(L96,time[i],v[i],time[i+1]-time[i])

# Plot 3d plot of first 3 coordinates
from mpl_toolkits import mplot3d

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8, 5))
ax = plt.axes(projection='3d', elev=40, azim=-50)
ax.plot3D(v[:,0,0], v[:,1,0], v[:,2,0],'g', lw=0.2)
ax.plot3D(v[:,0,1], v[:,1,1], v[:,2,1],'r', lw=0.2)
ax.plot3D(v[:,0,2], v[:,1,2], v[:,2,2],'b', lw=0.2)
ax.set_xlabel('$v_1$')
ax.set_ylabel('$v_2$')
ax.set_zlabel('$v_3$')
ax.set_title(f"N={N}")
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. If you check the Lorenz 96 description, it is a system of N differential equation, which N is number of variables. Therefore, in every iteration the L96 function produces a vector of N values that should be considered by Runge-Kutta method to solve the problem. I ran your code but is does not work because considers vector v with only one value in every loop that can not be used as the input of L96 function.

Comment: It works perfectly well after correcting the copy-paste error with k4, For N=3 the system converges to a fixed point, for N=4 it seems that it ends up in a periodic cycle, for N=5 the solution looks chaotic.

Comment: Thank you again for your answer. I slightly modified your code and put the complete code in your answer to make it easy for readers to easily follow it.